# ArcTan apply to nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, trigonometry

I have a coordinate system generated by :

```
coord = Table[{x, y}, {x, 5}, {y, 5}]
```

I would like to calculate `ArcTan(y/x)` and apply to `coord`:

```
ArcTan[#2/#1] & /@ coord
```

I am not sure what's wrong with my function. Could you help me to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `Apply` third argument.

Comment: Additionally, have a look at the two-arguments version of `ArcTan`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noone's addressed the actual question yet. There are three things wrong with your approach:

1. You are expecting an output `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}.... {x25,y25}}` but when you use `Table` with multiple iterators, it creates a nested list:

   ```
   {
       {
           {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}
       }, 
       {
           {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}
       }, 
       {   
           {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}
       }, 
       {
           {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}
       }, 
       {
           {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}
       }
   }
   ```
2. Even if the list were in the form you expected, you are doing:

   ```
   {ArcTan[    (#2/#1)& [{xn,yn}]    ]}
   ```

   Can you see what's wrong with that? As the error message suggests, you cannot fill slot `#2` when you only have a single argument. I know what you intended to do, and for this you need to use `Apply` to replace the head of `List[xn,yn]` so that it becomes `(#2/#1)&[xn,yn]`.
3. $(-x,-y)$ will be assigned the same result as $(x,y)$. The $\arctan$ function of one argument only has a unique range of $\pi$. This is a common issue (especially programming), and so sometimes we talk about an $\arctan$ function with two arguments $\arctan(x,y)$ which can give proper results for all values of $x,y$. In *Mathematica*, we can use this with `ArcTan[x,y]`.

---

### Solution:

```
coord = Table[{x, y}, {x, 5}, {y, 5}];
coord = Flatten[coord,1]; (* In general, replace 1 with the number of iterators minus 1. i.e. use a 2 for 3D coordinates*)
ArcTan@@@coord

Output:

{\[Pi]/4, ArcTan[2], ArcTan[3], ArcTan[4], ArcTan[5], ArcTan[1/2], \[Pi]/4, ArcTan[3/2], ArcTan[2], ArcTan[5/2], ArcTan[1/3], ArcTan[2/3], \[Pi]/4, ArcTan[4/3], ArcTan[5/3], ArcTan[1/4], ArcTan[1/2], ArcTan[3/4], \[Pi]/4, ArcTan[5/4], ArcTan[1/5], ArcTan[2/5], ArcTan[3/5], ArcTan[4/5], \[Pi]/4}
```

### Update per comment:

If you want to preserve the nested structure of the coordinates, then you can use `Apply` and specify the level. For the nested list above, we use a level of `2` because the the coordinate lists `{x,y}` are contained within a list within a list (i.e. are at level `2`).

```
Apply[ArcTan,coord,{2}]

Output:
{{\[Pi]/4, ArcTan[2], ArcTan[3], ArcTan[4], ArcTan[5]}, {ArcTan[1/2], \[Pi]/4, ArcTan[3/2], ArcTan[2], ArcTan[5/2]}, {ArcTan[1/3], ArcTan[2/3], \[Pi]/4, ArcTan[4/3], ArcTan[5/3]}, {ArcTan[1/4], ArcTan[1/2], ArcTan[3/4], \[Pi]/4, ArcTan[5/4]}, {ArcTan[1/5], ArcTan[2/5], ArcTan[3/5], ArcTan[4/5], \[Pi]/4}}
```

Comment: wow, you're the one that fully address my code issue in a clear and logical way. Appreciate your answer very much. But your code will reduce one dimension in the result but still I get your idea!

Comment: @cj9435042 - I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I think your code should has something like : `Partition[ArcTan@@@coord,5] ` in this case to make the dimension exactly. Sorry for not mentioning this clearly in my description!

Comment: @cj9435042 - okay, see my edit. Although my answer is now basically the same as Carl's.

Comment: Thank you for the updating!

Answer (score 7):

Using the 2-arg version of ArcTan (as suggested by @SjoerdCdeVries):

```
Apply[ArcTan, coord, {2}]
```

> {{π/4, ArcTan[2], ArcTan[3], ArcTan[4], ArcTan[5]}, {ArcTan[1/2], π/4,
>      ArcTan[3/2], ArcTan[2], ArcTan[5/2]}, {ArcTan[1/3], ArcTan[2/3], π/4, 
>     ArcTan[4/3], ArcTan[5/3]}, {ArcTan[1/4], ArcTan[1/2], ArcTan[3/4], π/4, 
>     ArcTan[5/4]}, {ArcTan[1/5], ArcTan[2/5], ArcTan[3/5], ArcTan[4/5], π/4}}

Or, you can tweak @Coolwater's fine answer:

```
coordNew = coord;
coordNew[[All, All, 0]] = ArcTan;
coordNew
```

> {{π/4, ArcTan[2], ArcTan[3], ArcTan[4], ArcTan[5]}, {ArcTan[1/2], π/4,
>      ArcTan[3/2], ArcTan[2], ArcTan[5/2]}, {ArcTan[1/3], ArcTan[2/3], π/4, 
>     ArcTan[4/3], ArcTan[5/3]}, {ArcTan[1/4], ArcTan[1/2], ArcTan[3/4], π/4, 
>     ArcTan[5/4]}, {ArcTan[1/5], ArcTan[2/5], ArcTan[3/5], ArcTan[4/5], π/4}}

Comment: Also `ArcTan @@@ # & /@ coord`

Answer (score 6):

Other ways:

```
ArcTan[coord[[All, All, 2]]/coord[[All, All, 1]]]

(* Or *)

coordNew = coord;
coordNew[[All, All, 0]] = ArcTan[#2/#] &
coordNew
```

Comment: Or even simpler is `coordNew[[All, All, 0]] = ArcTan`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ArcTan[#2/#1] & @@@ # & /@ coord
```

or

```
 ArcTan[#2/#1] & @@@ Transpose /@ coord
```

or

```
Map[ArcTan[#[[2]]/#[[1]]] &, coord, {-2}]
```

> {{Pi /4, ArcTan[2], ArcTan[3], ArcTan[4],   ArcTan[5]},
>     {ArcTan[1/2], Pi/4, ArcTan[3/2], ArcTan[2],  ArcTan[5/2]},
>     {ArcTan[1/3], ArcTan[2/3], Pi/4, ArcTan[4/3],   ArcTan[5/3]},
>     {ArcTan[1/4], ArcTan[1/2], ArcTan[3/4], Pi /4,  ArcTan[5/4]},
>     {ArcTan[1/5], ArcTan[2/5], ArcTan[3/5],   ArcTan[4/5], Pi/4}}

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pattern matching

`coord /. {x_, y_} :> ArcTan[y/x]`

**Edit**: I just realised this would fail if the list had just two pairs, in which case `x_` would match the first pair and `y_` the second.

But you could do something like this:

`Table[Pair[x, y], {x, 5}, {y, 5}] /. Pair[x_, y_] :> ArcTan[y/x]`

[btw, are you sure you mean `ArcTan[y/x]`, as opposed to `ArcTan[y,x]`? The latter takes into account the quadrant of (x, y)]